# I want to insert the large text through comment box. How can I do this in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I was trying to submit a very long message(say more than 2000letters) in the comment box of a form. but getting "comment has not been submitted". Please check the code below:

I have changed the type of comment inside the database to TEXT as well as MEDIUMTEXT and also LONGTEXT but nothing works. It is still showing "Comment has not been submitted".

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $cs_name = $_POST['name'];
        $cs_email = $_POST['email'];
        $cs_comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $cs_image = implode(',', $_FILES['image']['name']);
        $cs_images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $cs_image_tmp =  $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $cs_image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $cs_rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $cs_date = time();
        if(empty($cs_name) or empty($cs_email) or empty($cs_comment))
        {
            $error_msg = "All (*) feilds are compulsary";
        }  
        else
        {
            $cs_query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `date`, `name`, 
            `username`, `comp_id`, `email`, `image`, `comment`, 
            `rating`,`status`, `type`) VALUES (NULL, '$cs_date', '$cs_name', 
            'user', '$comp_id', '$cs_email', 
            '$cs_image', '$cs_comment', '$cs_rating', 'pending', 'C')";
            if(mysqli_query($con, $cs_query))
            {
                $msg = "Comment Submitted and waiting for Approval";
                for($i=0; $i<=count($cs_image_tmp)-1;$i++)
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($cs_image_tmp[$i], 
                        "admin/images/uploded/$cs_images[$i]");
                }
                header('Location: companies.php?comp_id='.$comp_id.'');
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                $error_msg = "Comment has not be submitted";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

It should submit a very long comment(say more than 2000 letters successfully and store it in a database.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: Hello, @DeepakTyagi first you echo your insert query after that copy your query and paste in the SQL database table and check.

Comment: @TarangP See when i send a short message there is no error. but when i insert large text the else query is exceuted (i.e Comment has not been submitted).

Comment: @SubhashPatel Hello, Thank You for your comment. see there is no error in the query it is working fine but when i try to send long text in comment box then it executes the else part that is Comment has not been submitted. but for short text say two or three line it is working fine.

Comment: instead of `$error_msg = "Comment has not be submitted";` try `printf("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($link));` or `die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($link));` One of them should output a more informative mysqli error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got my answer. i have added an if condition before for loop of move_uploded_files. that was creating problem.

```
    if(!empty($cs_images)){
        for($i=0; $i<=count($cs_image_tmp)-1;$i++){
        move_uploaded_file($cs_image_tmp[$i], "admin/images/uploded/$cs_images[$i]");
            }
        }
```

Thanks alot guys for your comments.